# .htaccess: work with specific file and directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a file tree like below...

```
.htaccess
index.php
includes
   css
   js
   xml
   images
      apple.jpg
      orange.jpg
      date.jpg
      berry.jpg
      .
      .
      .
      waterlemon.jpg
      banana.jpg
   file
      001.txt
      002.txt
      003.txt
      .
      .
      .
      100.txt
```

I am using below code for `.htaccess` to ***block every file and directory*** except `index.php` in the `root` directory...

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from All

<Files "index.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    allow from all
</Files>
```

now I need to allow only `apple.jpg`, `date.jpg`, `berry.jpg` & `banana.jpg` from the `images` folder... moreover, I also need to allow everything from the `file` folder... so that any one can directly access to any file from `001.txt` to `100.txt`... How can I do that...??

***I don't want to use more than one .htaccess file***

Comment: If you have access to the server configuration it is generally a much better idea to use the central configuration for such purposes instead of .htaccess files.

Comment: @arkascha I don't have access to server configuration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file/(.+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/images/(apple|date|berry|banana)\.jpg$
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

This code will only allow access to:

- (apple.jpg, date.jpg, berry.jpg, banana.jpg) from your
  `/includes/images/` folder.
- Your `index.php` file.
- Any file from your `/file/` directory.

Otherwise it will forbid access to any other file and will serve *403 Forbidden* error.

**PS: You don't need this code below in your .htaccess file anymore.**

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from All

<Files "index.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I didn't notice the other part of your question. I just updated my code above to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your update... please put an up vote for this question if you think the question can be helpful for others too...

Comment: friend, your code is returning `500 Internal Server Error`... please review your code...

Comment: I tried it on my website and it's working fine. Is my code the only code you have in your .htaccess or there is anything else?

Comment: I tried it again and it really works just fine on my web host. Can you please paste here your old .htaccess?

Comment: I used your code only... not a single letter more... besides, your codes look good... I don't understand why it's returning 500 Internal Server Error...

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with your host and this is why I'm asking you to paste your last .htaccess before you add my code. I'm sure there is some option that need to be added to our new code. Just paste your last working .htaccess and I'll look into it.

Comment: Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from All

<Files "index.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    allow from all
</Files>

Comment: friend... do you know which language is used for .htaccess...??

Comment: I'm really sure it has something to do with your web host. Is it GoDaddy? Just to check similar cases and try to solve it.

Comment: This code will work just fine if you tested it on a live host and your current issue is a separate issue. It has more to do with running mod_rewrite on WAMP server more than to do with my code. Anyway, are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your WAMP server? and what is exact local of your file on the server right now?

Comment: I sovled the `500 Internal Server Error`... mod_rewrite was disabled... but friend, now the code is throwing a `403 Error, Forbidden` for any link... please re-check your code... sorry for all the hassle...

Comment: Great. Again, as I told you in my last comment, I think it has more to do with WAMP than my code. I'm sure this time it's more about your website path on WAMP. Can you please tell me the exact path to your website on the WAMP server?

Comment: the path is `A:\WAMP\www\project_3598` where `project_3598` is the root folder...

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your new update. Please test it out and let me know.

Comment: same as before... `You don't have permission to access /project_3598/index.php on this server.`

Comment: Friend, I have edited your answer... my codes are working greatly... please check if everything is fine... after you accept the update, I will accept your answer...

Comment: Actually I reversed back my code to the latest one and I'll leave it as it is. As I told you, the code will work correctly on a live host and there is something wrong or missing on your WAMP that making it not work correctly. Just try it yourself on a live host and just work with your current working code.

Comment: as you are so confident... better to close the post... by the by I have got my solve... hope your answer will work for anyone else who want to do the same like me... thanks for your time and answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can block type file as I do in my web site.

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) //www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule \.(sql)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(txt)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(zip)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(rar)$ - [F]
```

add this line to your htaccess change the domain name and change the type file as you can see in the code this will help you :-)